# Godot Engine crash when Export with custom build template

Tags: godot

I was following a tutorial of setting up a custom build for Android in Godot from [this link](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/export/android_custom_build.html?). I am very sure that I have followed all the instructions, but godot engine always crash (white screen) without showing any error message, when i tried to use one-click deploy. The screen stuck at here:

[image]
[image]

I am using Godot 3.2.2. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem first. In my case, the problem was with `JDK` version mismatch. Make sure you are using the `jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot version`.
here is my screenshot: Editor Setting > Android
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. My problem was solved by waiting the white screen to run for some hours (due to my poor internet connection speed). After that, the build was just run smoothly.